# Error : org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionInterceptor

Tags: spring, hibernate

i have a problem in my spring configuration file application-context.xml
please help!!
i receive this error

```html
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionInterceptor
 at org.springframework.transaction.config.AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser$AopAutoProxyConfigurer.configureAutoProxyCreator(AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.java:127)
 at org.springframework.transaction.config.AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.parse(AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.java:84)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:74)
 at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.namespaces.DelegatingNamespaceHandlerResolver$ElementTrackingNamespaceHandler.parse(DelegatingNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:177)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1424)
 at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$ErrorSuppressingBeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeansConfig.java:1420)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1414)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:187)
 at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$ToolingFriendlyBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(BeansConfig.java:1350)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:110)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
 at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$2.registerBeanDefinitions(BeansConfig.java:404)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
 at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$2.loadBeanDefinitions(BeansConfig.java:388)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
 at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$3.call(BeansConfig.java:447)
 at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$3.call(BeansConfig.java:1)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

this is my configuration file application-context.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.1.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd">

  
   <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bd_ao" />
      <property name="username" value="root" />
      <property name="password" value="root" />
   </bean>
   
   <bean id="sessionFactoy" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
     <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
     <property name="annotatedClasses">
      <list>
       <value>ao.medasys.ma.entities.Boncommande</value>
       <value>ao.medasys.ma.entities.Bonlivraison</value>
       <value>ao.medasys.ma.entities.Candidature</value>
       <value>ao.medasys.ma.entities.Caution</value>
       <value>ao.medasys.ma.entities.Client</value>
       <value>ao.medasys.ma.entities.Equipetravail</value>
       <value>ao.medasys.ma.entities.Facture</value>
       <value>ao.medasys.ma.entities.Fournisseur</value>
       <value>ao.medasys.ma.entities.Marche</value>
       <value>ao.medasys.ma.entities.Membre</value>
       <value>ao.medasys.ma.entities.Produit</value>
       <value>ao.medasys.ma.entities.Ville</value>
      </list>
     </property>
     <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <props>
             <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
         </props>
     </property>
   </bean>
   
   <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
     <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactoy"></property>
   </bean>
   
   <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
   <context:annotation-config/>
   <context:component-scan base-package="ao.medasys.ma.entities"></context:component-scan>
   

</beans>
```

i have error in this line exactly !!

```html
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

i have all my jar files in the project i work with spring 4 and hibernate 3 !

Comment: do you have `spring-tx-x.x.x.jar` jar in your `WEB-INF/lib` folder ?

Comment: remove transaction manager from `<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />` keep only this much  `<tx:annotation-driven />`

Comment: still the same problem !

Comment: @ABDELLAHAYOUBHAMIDI - were you able to fix the issue ? I am also getting the same error, how did you fix it ?